# VSCode Typescript param default mis-typing issue

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am making a function like this:

```
function myFunc({ flag1 = true } = { flag1: true }) {
  const myFlag = flag1;
}
```

My intention is that you can call `myFunc` without param.  It will default to `{flag1: true}`, or you can passing an object to it.

But when I do `myFunc({ flag1: false });`, I get this warning in vscode:

```
(property) flag1?: true
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2322)
```

To get rid of this, I needed to add typing:

```
  function myFunc({ flag1 = true }: { flag1: boolean } = { flag1: true }) {
    const myFlag = flag1;
  }
```

Is this the only way go about this?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
function myFunc({ flag1 } = { flag1: true }) {
  const myFlag = flag1;
}
```

The `flag1` will be `true` when using the default object.

The type definition is inferred as:

```js
function myFunc({ flag1 }?: { flag1: boolean }): void
```